# How do you obtain data from an HTML element using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am currently using 1.2.x version of AngularJs and I'm trying to retrieve the `data` from the HTML element:

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller" data-foo="bar1">
<div ng-controller="mycontroller" data-foo="bar2"></div>
```

I want to retrieve the values of `foo` and have a result of `[bar1, bar2]`. I thought about using `$.data()`, but want to avoid that. The controller `mycontroller` is repeated on purpose and is not a mistake. Any advice on how to retrieve the data in the HTML element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `data` attributes within your controller:

```
app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope, $attrs) {
    console.log($attrs.foo);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73YwN/1/)